# Stone Arch Bridge

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex

I would like to reproduce the following with TikZ, but have not been able to do so. The first one is easy, I think, but I cannot build the bridge... Help, please.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (0.2,0.2) -- (0.4,0) -- (0.2,-0.2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Math and angles.

You can use the `scale` key or the `x` and `y` keys to change the size of arch.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand*\myAng   {7.5}
\newcommand*\myArches{5} % starting with 0
\coordinate (@);
\foreach[evaluate={\c=\i/\myArches*100;}] \i in {0,...,\myArches}
  \draw[rotate=-(\i-(\myArches-1)/2)*2*\myAng+\myAng, fill=red!\c!blue!50]
    (@) -- +(90+\myAng:1)
        -- +([shift=(90-\myAng:1)]right:1)
        -- +(right:1) coordinate (@)
        -- cycle;

\draw[rotate= (\myArches+1)*\myAng]          (0, -0.2)     rectangle +(-1.4, 1.4);
\draw[rotate=-(\myArches+1)*\myAng] ([shift={(0, -0.2)}]@) rectangle +( 1.4, 1.4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: If those arches aren't all the same size with the same angles and the same angle on both sides you can still use the same technique, save the coordinate (here `@`) of the lower right corner of each quadrilateral and use it as the start (lower left) point of your next one.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a double line to draw the bridge and decorate it with vertical lines to mimic stones:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=ticks]
  \draw [double distance=1.7mm] (0,0) arc [start angle=30, end angle=151, radius=2cm];
  \draw [decorate] (0,0) arc [start angle=30, end angle=151, radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One can use a chain of `trapezium` shapes. This has the advantage that the various corners and so on are accessible as the node anchors for later use.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={alpha=40;% opening angle of the bridge 
    n=6;% number of inner bricks
    w=1;% brick height
    beta=alpha/n;% auxiliary angle
},line join=round]
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myn}{n}   
 \path coordinate (tmp) node[anchor=south east,shift={(alpha-90:w*0.1cm)},minimum size=w*1.2cm,rectangle,draw,rotate=alpha](L){}
 foreach \i in {1,...,\myn}
 {node[trapezium,draw,outer sep=0pt,trapezium angle={-90+beta},minimum height=1cm,anchor=bottom left corner,rotate={alpha-2*(\i-0.5)*beta}](t-\i) {}
 (t-\i.bottom right corner) }
 node[anchor=south west,shift={(-alpha-90:w*0.1cm)},minimum size=w*1.2cm,rectangle,draw,rotate=-alpha](R){};   
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image]